# generating mutlple buttons using while loops

Tags: javascript, php, loops, button

I am generating multiple toggle buttons using a while loop in php to hide AND SHOW content in my website. how do I ensure that clicking one of them does not open all. how do I ensure that each one is unique

I have tried looping the buttons and giving them incrementing Id and names , however I cant seem to figure out how I can use that to  call each button uniquely.

```
<?php
$sql         = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result      = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo " <form method='GET'>";
        echo '<button type="submit" name="contact" class="btn btn-light btn-radius btn-brd grd1 " value="con">contact</button>';
        echo "</form>";
        $contact = $_GET['contact'];
        if ($contact == "con") {

            echo "<h3>cellphone: </h3>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['user_last'] . "</p>";
            echo "<h3>email: </h3>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['user_email'] . "</p>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

?>
```

so this code allows me to create multiple buttons that hide some text , however  when I click on one button , all of them get clicked at once, I want to be able to see what is hidden by one button at a time

Comment: are you using Jquery or pure javascript for hide/show event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an incrementing variable and concatenate a class/id with the variable.

```
$i = 0;
if ($resultCount > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo " <form method='GET'>";
        echo '<button type="submit" name="contact" class="btn btn-light btn-radius btn-brd grd'.$i.'" value="con">contact</button>';
        echo "</form>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
$i = 0; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  echo " <form method='GET'>"; 
  echo '<button type="submit" name="contact' . $i . '" value="con">contact</button>';
  echo "</form>";
  $i++;
}
```

Or use JS to hide  by it's ID.

then it would be:

```
echo '<button id="'. $i .'" onclick="jsFunction(this)" name="contact" value="con">contact</button>';
```

and afterwards just hide div with JS function.

Comment: ```   if ($resultCount > 0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   echo " <form method='GET'>";
        echo '<button type="submit" name="contact" class="btn btn-light btn-radius btn-brd grd1" value="'.$i.'">contact</button>';
        echo "</form>";
        $i++;
    $contact=$_GET ['contact'];
     if($contact==$i-1) { 
     
     echo"<h3>cellphone: </h3>";
               echo"<p>".$row['user_last']."</p>";
      echo "<h3>email: </h3>";
     echo "<p>".$row['user_email']."</p>";}
           echo "</div>";
     
    
  }``` this was the final code.